# Parsing and visualizing outputs of piecewise gradients

Tags: visualization, piecewise

I have a function

```
tropGradient[poly_, zerosList_] := 
 Module[{grad, pieces}, 
  grad = Grad[
    TropicalizeTuples[
     CoefficientsAndExponentsList[poly, zerosList]], {x, y}];
  grad]
```

where `TropicalizeTuples[CoefficientsAndExponentsList[poly, zerosList]]`  just gives a function of form `Max[a1x+b1y+c1,a2x+b2y+c2,...]`. Gradients of functions of this form look rather complicated - usually piecewise functions.

For instance

```
Grad[Max[0,2 x,1+x,2 y,1+y,3+x+y],{x,y}]
```

returns

> [image]

This should ultimately be a set of 6 gradient vectors, over different regions of the plane - seen visually here

> [image]

All functions of the form I've given should be a finite set of gradient vectors, each defined and equal over some region. How can I visualize this - and make it clear what the vectors are.

Ideally, it would be great to have the plane seperated into regions, and in each region, a text description giving the gradient vector for that region.

But any way of parsing these terrible outputs is invited!

Here is the [code](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/kevintang634489/Published/subdivision.nb) and outputs.

Comment: There's very little we can practically do without running code. You need to include all definitions and an example of input.

Comment: Alright. I'm not sure how much it'll help, but https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/kevintang634489/Published/subdivision.nb contains all the definitions and inputs.

Comment: After all, I wrote this program rather messily. The key thing is that we're passing a function of form Max[f1,f2,...] where f1,f2,.. are linear functions of x and y into Grad[]. Gradients of functions of this form should be finite sets of vectors defined over certain regions depending on which linear function is maximum in the given region.